# How get viewModelScope from hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

My Paging class

```
 class UserDataSource @Inject constructor(private val listService: ListService, private val scope: CoroutineScope): PageKeyedDataSource<Int, News>()
```

I need get  viewModelScope from ViewModel, but I always get error when try and don't find how add CoroutineScope from my viewModel

Comment: you can try using `@Assisted` injection